# unauthorized_scope_error in LinkedIn oAuth2 authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am following the official *Microsoft* instructions in [Sign in with Linkedin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context) (there are also the *Linkedin* instructions [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2)), which also link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow) for the authorization code flow. As instructed, I have set up a linkedin application and used the client id and secret to initiate an oAuth 2 flow, requesting the `r_liteprofile` and `r_emailaddress` scopes.

Instead of getting the login form, I am redirected to my callback url with the following params:

`error: unauthorized_scope_error
error_description: Scope &quot;r_liteprofile&quot; is not authorized for your application
state: cfa970987c9a3c2178dddeda0d81dab3e00dce4c683098d6`

This is the list of default scopes (which, as per the documentation, are the ones granted if you don't specify a list of scopes yourself), and the `r_liteprofile` is not in there.

[image]

Is the documentation out of date, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 44):

We have to enable "Sign In with LinkedIn" under the products tab, only then you can avail that scope (r_liteprofile and/or r_emailaddress) and services.

[image]

This goes for the review process(System takes max 60 mins to approve) and If your request has been approved, the relevant product will be moved to the "Added products" section.

[image]

Comment: omg thank you so much. They like never mentioned this in their docs.

Comment: Yeah, I too wasted my time lot, glad this helped you.

Answer (score 8):

This happened to me the other day but somehow I was able to get around the issue. The [new Microsoft API docs for LinkedIn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context) are up to date. The docs on LinkedIn Developers portal will soon be outdated:

> **Important update:** All developers need to migrate to Version 2.0 of our APIs and OAuth 2.0 by March 1, 2019.

A few things to try:

- Register a new LinkedIn OAuth 2.0 developer application - newly registered applications have access to the new V2 API
- Try removing the `r_liteprofile` scope or revert back to `r_basicprofile`

Comment: Yeah, I changed the scopes to `["r_basicprofile"]` and it bypassed the error.

Answer (score 5):

**My little contribution in 2021.**

It seems like Linkedin keeps changing the value for scopes.

On the Linkedin developer portal looking under **OAuth 2.0 scopes** section in the Auth tab, I found the values that finally worked for me.

PS: Make sure to enable Sign-in from the product Tab.
[image: Linkedin API scope]

Comment: Thanks, 2023 scope for my app is : `"openid%20profile%20email"` , just simple profile & email no more prefixes!

Answer (score 5):

**Post August 2023:**

For those wondering, LinkedIn changed their oauth scopes again, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/sign-in-with-linkedin-v2

Scope names are now "email"/etc, not "r_emailaddress" any more.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to Products in the LinkedIn Developer Console and select Sign in with LinkedIn.

The verification process takes a few moments and then r_emailaddress and r_liteprofile should appear under your permissions.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to include the following scope in your OAuth2 authentication request:
scope: 'openid email profile'

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was to click "select" next to "Sign In with LinkedIn" on the LinkedIn developers console for my app.

Answer (score 0):

We must add a product with Sign In with LinkedIn (click on select): [Product menu with "Sign in with linkedin" selected.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zZ1l.png).
Then, in the auth menu: OAuth 2.0 scopes, we get this : [Auth menu scope.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMl2b.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering an "*invalid_scope_error*" while working with LinkedIn API in Python, it typically means that the requested scope in your authentication request is not valid or not allowed for your application.

**For 2023** and further the scope has been changed from **r_liteprofile**, **r_emailaddress** and **w_member_social** to **profile**, **email** and **w_member_social**

you can try with below code

```
import requests

client_id = 'your_client_id'
redirect_uri = 'your_redirect_uri'
scope = 'profile email w_member_social'  # Modify this based on your required scopes

authorization_url = f'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&scope={scope}'

print(f'Please go to the following URL to reauthorized your application: {authorization_url}')
```

:)