# Error: No code parameter provided by LinkedIn

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I a getting started with LinkedIN API and after running the following code, it opens a linkedIn window which says:

"Bummer, something went wrong.
In five seconds, you will be redirected to: 127.0.0.1"

After 5 seconds it takes me to URL:

http://127.0.0.1:5000/callback?error=unauthorized_scope_error&error_description=Scope+%26quot%3Br_basicprofile%26quot%3B+is+not+authorized+for+your+application&state=123456

With the message "Error: No code parameter provided by LinkedIn. Check your application settings."

```py
import requests
from flask import Flask, redirect, request

app = Flask(__name__)

# Define your LinkedIn application credentials

client_id = 'xxx'
client_secret = 'xxx'
redirect_uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/callback'
authorization_base_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization'
token_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken'
state = '123456'  # This should be a randomly generated value in production!

@app.route('/')
def login():
\# Step 1: Redirect the user to LinkedIn's OAuth 2.0 authorization page to get the authorization code.
params = {
'response_type': 'code',
'client_id': client_id,
'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
'state': state,
'scope': 'r_emailaddress',
}

    auth_url = requests.Request('GET', authorization_base_url, params=params).prepare().url
    return redirect(auth_url)

@app.route('/callback')
def callback():
\# Step 2: Capture the code parameter LinkedIn sends to our callback URL
code = request.args.get('code')
returned_state = request.args.get('state')

    # Check if the state matches to prevent CSRF attacks
    if returned_state != state:
        return "Error: State value did not match. Possible CSRF attack.", 400
    
    if not code:
        return "Error: No code parameter provided by LinkedIn. Check your application settings.", 400
    
    # Step 3: Exchange the authorization code for an access token
    token_data = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': code,
        'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret
    }
    token_response = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data)
    token_json = token_response.json()
    
    if 'access_token' not in token_json:
        return f"Error obtaining access token. {token_json.get('error_description')}", 400
    
    access_token = token_json['access_token']
    
    # At this point, you have the access token and can make authenticated LinkedIn API calls.
    # Example: Fetching profile details (just for demonstration)
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}
    profile_response = requests.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me', headers=headers)
    return profile_response.json()

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

I tried different scopes like "r_emailaddress" and "r_basicprofile". I also have access to the following products in the image:
[image]

I have reviewed this same problem but nothing worked because the platform has changed a lot in 5 years:
[unauthorized_scope_error in LinkedIn oAuth2 authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53479131/unauthorized-scope-error-in-linkedin-oauth2-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by going to https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/213979188/auth

Then using the scope listed in my portal under OAuth 2.0 scopes.

[image]